# JApplet scrollbar using JScrollPane shows but doesn't scroll Graphics2D content outside screen

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, graphics2d, japplet

I am trying to add a scrollbar to a JApplet component. I know I shouldn't use it and should rather use JPanel, but for sake of semplicity I'll leave it like it, as in a tutorial I am following.

As you can see I tried adding a ScrollPane component, and add to it the applet. Then I add the scrollpane to the frame.

The result is that I can see a vertical scrollbar, but that it does have the ability to scrool. Actually the scroll cursor is missing. And the up and down arrows don't scrooll too. I'd like to scroll down to the part of the line I've drawn that went outside the visible area.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class App {

    private App() {
        final int WINHSIZE = 800;
        final int WINVSIZE = 600;

        class MyJApplet extends JApplet {

            public void init() {
                setBackground(Color.black);
                setForeground(Color.white);
            }

            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                        g2.drawLine(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
                }
            }
        }


        JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JApplet applet = new MyJApplet();
        JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(applet, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        f.getContentPane().add("Center", myScrollPane);
        applet.init();
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(WINHSIZE, WINVSIZE));
        f.setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'll leave it like it, as in a tutorial I am following.

Well your tutorial is old and you should NOT be following it. Instead you should be learning how to create a JFrame the normal way.

That is you do custom painting on a JPanel by overriding the `paintComponent()` method and you add the panel to the frame. You should NOT override paint(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial (which is a far better tutorial to follow) on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for more information. You need to make sure to override the `getPreferredSize()` method so the scrollbars can work properly.

```
f.getContentPane().add("Center", myScrollPane);
```

That is not how you add a Component to a Container. You would never hardcode a constraint like that. Also you should be using:

```
 add(component, constraint)
```

The BorderLayout will contain fields you can use to identify the constraint.

People don't use `f.getContentPane().add(...)` anymore. Since JDK4 you can use `f.add(...)`. As I said your tutorial is way out of date.

Look at the table of contents of the Swing tutorial. The examples are more up to date and will provide a better design for your application. For example you should be creating GUI components on the Event Dispatch Thread, which your code is NOT doing. Read the tutorial on `Concurrency` to understand why this is important.

Comment: Thanks. I believe they should take offline the example at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/gui_line.htm . I'm sure a lot of wrong code and questions originates from there! Also I think the use of `f.getContentPane().add(...)` in place of the more recent `f.add(...)` is not concurring to the problem, but yes I would have pointed out it too :) And I know of the importance of EDT and avoiding blocking the main thread. Time ago I developed a small app correctly using EDT together with a thread pool for concurrect connections, and read all about it. But now it's all gone again :)

Comment: Changed to Jpanel, all is working. Thanks again for setting me back on the right path. Anyone else ending up here, don't forget to also call `super.paintComponent(g);` before anything else in paintComponent ovverride.

Answer (score 2):

You've set them to be always visible. That means even if there is no need to scroll - they'll still appear. If you do not want to vertical scroll bar to appear, you can just do:

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(applet);
```

Or

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(applet,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

---

Regardless of how you implement it, the scroll bar will only be enabled and usable when it is *needed*. It may be visible (as your code shows), but there is no point for it to enable scrolling, so it won't allow you to.

If the size of `applet` is determined to be bigger than the available size of the `myScrollPane`, then the needed scroll bars will be activated. This can be done by adding more components, or overriding the `setPreferredSize`, `setSize` methods of the `applet` as needed.

---

For example, this code sample shows how the scroll bar (in this case horizontal) will only be activated when needed. The rest of the time, it will be visible - but not active - which is what you are seeing.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll Bar Test");
final JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(content, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    content.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
}

frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice gif :) Now that I've solved the problem of scroll bar cursor not showing at all (even though it *was* needed) I'm trying to understand if that works dynamically too with Graphics2d components, i.e. on mouse click I will draw a line that goes 200 pixel off the JPanel. Will ScrollBars resize accordingly?

Comment: @jj_ unfortunately, it won't. You can however change the size when needed. You can however calculate the "working area" and then change the panel to fit that area through `setSize` or `setPreferredSize`.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Searched through whole net, couldn't find antrhing interesting. What about content panel has fixed size so that "label 3" will go down and "label 6" will go next down place and so on. my scrollpane does not show it.